# Is there an solution to print out ascii graphics when the data is on a array?

Tags: python, ascii

I have a set of information in a list `a`

```
a = [["*","-","-"],["-","*","-"],["-","-","*"]]
```

in which I would like to use a code so that my terminal will show:

```
*--
-*-
--*
```

I've tried:

```
print(a)
```

but it shows only the list

I've also tried:

```
print(a[0][0], a[1][0], a[2][0])
print(a[0][1], a[1][1], a[2][1])
print(a[0][2], a[1][2], a[2][2])
```

but it gives me spaces:

```
* - -
- * -
- - *
```

Comment: You could print it by `print(a[0][0], a[1][0], a[2][0], sep="")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join each list on an empty space

```
for l in a:
  print(''.join(l))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
for line in a:
  print(''.join(line))
```

Comment: This is identical to [One Cricketeer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69561345/16775594), and they answered first (although only by 20 seconds :-) ).

Comment: Yes, like 2.5 seconds before :) But sure